# Memory leak in C# Code

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I have a piece of code that going to the database every minute to check if there is any report that need to be run, and if there is any it runs it.

The issue is that my object initiation to a database class creates memory leak. If I look at task mgr "user Object" grown by 5 every time tick executing a code.

```
private void ReportRunTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataConnection dataConnection = new DataConnection(); *<-- when executing this line User Object increasing.*
            try
            {
                reportsToRun = dataConnection.GetListOfTheReportForReportRunTick();
                if (reportsToRun.Count > 0)
                    foreach (string report in reportsToRun)
                    {
                        logs("Starting Automatic report generatin", "Successful");
                        Thread TicketReportMethodThread = new Thread(() => GenerateReport(report, 1));
                        TicketReportMethodThread.Start();
                    }
                dataConnection = null;
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logs("Starting Automatic report generatin failed: " +ex.ToString(), "Error");
            }
            finally
            {
                reportsToRun.Clear();
            }
        }
```

**DataConnection class**

```
public List<string> GetListOfTheReportForReportRunTick()
{
    List<string> RepoerList = new List<string>();
    connString = "Server=xxx;Port=xxx;Database=xxx;Uid=xxx;password=xxxx;SslMode=none";
    using (MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT reportname FROM reports WHERE nextruntime < NOW()";
            mySqlConnection.Open();
            MySqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
            {
                RepoerList.Add(mySqlDataReader["reportname"].ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            hd.logs("Failed to get reports with reportstorun_tick Error: " + ex.ToString(), "Error");
            mySqlConnection.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            mySqlConnection.Close();
            mySqlConnection.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return RepoerList;
}
```

`DataConnection dataConnection = new DataConnection();` used in a few more places and this is the only one that causing an issue.

If I replace code in private void ReportRunTimer_Tick with code from public List GetListOfTheReportForReportRunTick() like bellow. Issue no longer exist, any ideas?

```
private void ReportRunTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> reportsToRun = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        connString = "Server=xxx;Port=xxx;Database=xxx;Uid=xxx;password=xxxx;SslMode=none";
        using (MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
                mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT reportname FROM reports WHERE nextruntime < NOW()";
                mySqlConnection.Open();
                MySqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
                {
                    reportsToRun.Add(mySqlDataReader["reportname"].ToString());
                }



                if (reportsToRun.Count > 0)
                    foreach (string report in reportsToRun)
                    {
                        logs("Starting Automatic report generatin", "Successful");
                        Thread TicketReportMethodThread = new Thread(() => GenerateReport(report, 1));
                        TicketReportMethodThread.Start();

                    }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                logs("Failed to get reports with reportstorun_tick Error: " + ex.ToString(), "Error");
                mySqlConnection.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                mySqlConnection.Close();
                mySqlConnection.Dispose();
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logs("Starting Automatic report generatin failed: " + ex.ToString(), "Error");
    }
    finally
    {
        reportsToRun.Clear();

    }

}
```

Issue is caused by

```
DataConnection dataConnection = new DataConnection(); *<-- when executing this line User Object increasing.*
reportsToRun = dataConnection.GetListOfTheReportForReportRunTick();
```

But I can't understand why.

Comment: Did you check your log that there are no exceptions occurring? In any case, I think using `using` is a good idea so you don't have to worry about opening/closing things.

Comment: Also realize that .NET is a garbage collected system.  Memory usage will increase as your program runs until the garbage collector kicks in.  At that point, some (but not necessarily all) of your memory will be reclaimed.  Depending on what you are using to measure your "leak", you may not see the result of this reclamation (though your apparent memory growth will appear to stop for a while),  If you want to force a garbage collection as part of your test, use `GC.Collect();`

Comment: ***Use a memory profiler***. Observing memory usage via task manager is highly misleading.

Comment: `mySqlConnection.Close();
            mySqlConnection.Dispose();` Remove those - they aren't doing anything since you are using `using`.

Comment: I tried replacing code from private void ReportRunTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) with code from public List<string> GetListOfTheReportForReportRunTick() and "leak" stopped. "User Objects" stopped increasing. Also I noticed that when reach 10,000 that's wen application always crashing.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] that we can copy and paste into a console app and reproduce the issue. It is key that is as small as possible while still compiling and exhibiting the issue you are experiencing. The bug is likely in `GenerateReport` so be sure to include that too.

Comment: Sure. Will Try to do that tomorrow.

Comment: Agree with spender, Visual Studio has a profiler built in and you will be able to see exactly what objects are accumulating.

Answer (score 2):

I think the memory leak is because you're not disposing your MySqlDataReader. You can do this by just wrapping it in a using statement like this:

```
using(MySqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()){
    while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
    {
        RepoerList.Add(mySqlDataReader["reportname"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I think SqlCommand also implements dispose, so you might want to try wrapping the usage of that in a using statement as well. Otherwise I don't see any other unmanaged resources in the code you've posted.In this case you may just want to just try and force garbage collection using ```System.GC.Collect()``` and see if that solves your problem.